# Catched exception is not handle with the correct method

Tags: java, exception

I have the simple code below :

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();

        try {
            t.throwAnotherException();
        } catch (AnotherException e) {
            t.handleException(e);
        }

        try {
            t.throwAnotherException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass().getName());
            t.handleException(e);
        }

    }

    public void throwAnotherException() throws AnotherException {
        throw new AnotherException();
    }

    public void handleException(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Handle Exception");
    }

    public void handleException(AnotherException e) {
        System.out.println("Handle Another Exception");
    }

}

class AnotherException extends Exception {

}
```

Why the method called in the second catch is the one with the signature `void handleException(Exception e)` whereas the kind of exception is `AnotherException`?

Comment: I didn't quite get your question, but I feel you are mixing the method name with exception name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overloaded methods are resolved at *compile time*, based on *formal parameter types*, not *runtime types*.

That means that if `B extends A`, and you have

```
void thing(A x);

void thing(B x);
```

then

```
B b = new B();
thing(b);
```

will look for a `thing()` that takes a `B`, because the formal type of `b` is `B`; but

```
A b = new B();
thing(b);
```

will look for a `thing()` that takes an `A`, because the formal type of `b` is `A`, even though its runtime actual type will be `B`.

In your code, the formal type of `e` is `AnotherException` in the first case, but `Exception` in the second case. The runtime type is `AnotherException` in each case.

Answer (score 0):

AnotherException extends Exception, which means that anywhere you use "Exception", using an instance of "AnotherException" will qualify.

You should probably read up on Extending Classes for a more detailed explanation of how this works as it's very important in programming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to test which `Exception` is gonna get caught, right?

Then modify your code to throw just one `Exception`:

```
    try {
        t.throwAnotherException();
    } catch (AnotherException e) {
        t.handleException(e);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getClass().getName());
        t.handleException(e);
    }
```

which is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`Exception` is the super class so if you write your catch clause with (Exception e) first it will always gets satisfy and get executed.

to improve your code you can modify your code as written below.

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();

        try {
            t.throwAnotherException();
        } catch (AnotherException e) {
            t.handleException(e);
        }

        try {
            t.throwAnotherException();
        }catch (AnotherException e) {
            t.handleException(e);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass().getName());
            t.handleException(e);
        }

    }

    public void throwAnotherException() throws AnotherException {
        throw new AnotherException();
    }

    public void handleException(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Handle Exception");
    }

    public void handleException(AnotherException e) {
        System.out.println("Handle Another Exception");
    }

}

class AnotherException extends Exception {

}
```